# Invert image pixels

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

I'm currently trying to convert a piece of matlab code to java. The purpose of the code is to invert and normalize the image pixels of an image file. In java, the pixels are stored in a byte array. Below is the Matlab code of importance:

```
inp2=1024.-inp.-min; %inp is the input array (double precision). min is the minimum value in that matrix.
```

The image is 16 bit, but is using only 10 bits for storage, so that's where the 1024 comes from (2^10). I know definitively that this code works in matlab. However, I'm personally not proficient in matlab, and my java translation isn't behaving the same way as its counterpart.

Below is the method where I've tried inverting the image matrix:

```
//bitsStored is the bit depth. In this test, it is 10.
//imageBytes is the pixel data in a byte array
public static short[] invert(int bitsStored) {
    short min = min(imageBytes);//custom method. Gets the minimum value in the byte array. 
    short range = (short) (2 << bitsStored);
    short[] holder = new short[imageBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.length; i++) {
        holder[i] = (short) (range - imageBytes[i] - min);
    }
    imageBytes = holder;
    return imageBytes;
}
```

However, instead of inverting the color channels, the image loses some data and becomes much harsher looking (higher contrast, less blend, etc). What am I doing wrong here?

Let me know if I can make anything clearer for you. Thank you.

**UPDATE**:
Hi, I have another question regarding this code. Can the above code (fixed to short[] not byte[]) be used in reverse on the same file? As in, if I rerun through this code using an inverted version of the original image, should I get the original input/image from the start of the program? The only problem with it I think is that the min value changes between runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte` has range from -128 to 127, it cannot hold 1024 different values. So either you need to use a wider type (like `short`) to model your points, or your byte array has to be unpacked before processing.

One more thing: `double` is floating point and it does not play well with integers used in the rest of your code. The following seems better:

```
short range = 1 << bitsStored; // 2^bitsStored
```

Comment: Excellent! This seems to have worked. I'll do some more testing and comment again if I have more questions. Thank you :).

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you're still around, but I was wondering if you could answer another question about this for me. Can the above code (assuming short[] not byte[]) be used in reverse on the same file? As in, if I rerun through this code using an inverted version of the original image, should I get the original input/image from the start of the program? The only problem with it I think is that the min value changes between runs.

Comment: I've posted another answer, it's too long for a comment

Answer (score 2):

Correct equation for inversion is:

```
 newValue[i] = maxPossibleValue - currentValue[i]
```

Your `maxPossibleValue` is 1024.

Other thing is that you can't have image with depth of 10 bits in array of bytes (cause they've 8 bits)

Comment: Let me fix that. Technically, it's 16 bit, but it's only using 10 of them.

Answer (score 1):

On your second question about the reversibility of your algorithm.

Your formula looks like `result[i] = 1024 - min(data) - data[i]` where data ranges from `0` to `1023`. Let's imagine that all your data points are `1023`. Then `min` is `1023`, so all the `result[i]` will be `-1022`.

So the `result` does not even fit in the same range as the `data`.

Then, if you run your algorithm with that `result` array to produce `result1`, all its points will be `1024 - (-1022) - (-1022)` i.e. `3068`, and not the original `1023`.

So the answer is not, double application of this algorithm does not produce result equal to the input.

Please note that the algorithm mentioned in another answer (`maxPossibleValue - currentValue[i]`) keeps range and it is reverses when applied twice.

BTW, it should be

```
short range = (short) (1 << bitsStored);
```

instead of

```
short range = (short) (2 << bitsStored);
```

to produce `2^bitsStored`.